# Construction Lines offset when added to fabric

Tags: geolocation, parcel-fabric, civil3d

We use geo-positioned CAD data then copy paste survey accurate data into our Parcel Fabric.  When we convert them to new parcels, the points move off the correct location by two to 5 feet.  What causes this offset and how can we keep this from happening?

Comment: what are you pasting into?

Comment: Is your CAD in the same coordinate system as Parcel Fabric? If not, you might reproject before copy/paste.

Comment: No,  I have put the Civil 3D CAD data in our ESRI coordinate base but the parcel fabric does not recognize the CAD Coordinate system.  Are you suggesting adding the ESRI Coordinate base before I import from catalog?  Is that correct?